# how can I modify a form dynamically and interactively in CakePHP?

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp, dynamic

What I want to do is:

- create a form with one input (combo box)
- depending on the user's choice in the combo box, other inputs should be added to the form..

for example, the form is for creating new users..

the combo box will contain a list of user types..

depending on the user type, fields are added to the form

for a `student`, we need (name, email), for a `teacher`, we need (name, email, phone, certificate), etc..

I already have the code for all the stuff..
I just need guide lines for this specific task

btw, i prefer to use jQuery for the javascript code..

any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 scenarios.

**Non Ajax**

1. Have an intermediary screen where the user selects what type of user he wants to add
2. Depending on the selection, switch the view and display the appropriate custom view for the user

**AJAX**

1. When the user selects the radio button, send a request to your controller and fetch the required form HTML for that user type. You can keep it in a view or as an element
2. Insert it into the DOM and then let the user fill it out and submit. (This won't work if you use the Security component though!)

You can use `$this->render()` to switch the views and `jQuery.load()` to get the AJAX going.

You could also *combine* these two methods so you get a full user experience. Basically, if JS is enabled you can do it the AJAX way and if not, you can use the intermediary method. Layering your functionality is good practice.

Comment: thanx a lot @JohnP.. i will start to implement that according to your guidance.. probably, i will use the Ajax version, cuz i don't wanna add more steps to the creation...
i'll let you know if i need more help..